# PHP parsing for specific strings in text area

Tags: php, parsing, post, search

I have been working on a PHP webpage to help me parse lots of data. It works but I would like it more robust .

So on my main page I have a text area that you can copy in as much information as you want. You click submit posts the data into a page that processes it

here is the code currently that parses it

```
 foreach ($textAr as $line) 


    if (substr( $line, 0, 2 ) == "IN") 
    {
        $line2 = $line;
        $textAr2 = explode("\r", $line2);
            $textAr2 = array_filter($textAr2, 'trim'); // remove any extra characters left behind
        foreach ($textAr2 as $line2) 
            {
                $length = strlen($line2);
                if ( $length == 10)
                {
                    if (substr( $line2, 0, 2 ) == "IN") 
                    {
                        $count++;
                        $line3 = ltrim($line2, 'IN');

                        echo $line3 . ",";
                    }

                }


            }
    }
```

the data that I input always has a format of

```
names   dates times summary stuffs      infostuffs  stats   names   dates   IN*somenumber
names    dates  times summary stuffs        infostuffs          names   dates   IN*somenumber
names   dates times summary stuffs      infostuffs  stats   names   dates   IN*somenumber
names   dates times summary stuffs      infostuffs  stats       dates   IN*somenumber
names   dates times summary stuffs      infostuffs  stats   names   dates   IN*somenumber
names   dates times summary stuffs      infostuffs  stats   names   dates   IN*somenumber
 names  dates times summary stuffs      infostuffs  stats   names   None    IN*somenumber
names   dates times summary stuffs      infostuffs  stats   names   dates   IN*somenumber
```

This works great, I know its not the most efficient but it works. 
However I want to make it more robust and I'm failing due to lack of coding knowledge. It is always going to be searching for a string that starts with "IN" and has 8 numbers after it. After that it strips the IN out and put it into a continuous string of numbers like `88888888,88888888,88888888,88888888,88888888,88888888,`
The , is critical as I use it for csv stuff

I want it to handle other formats 
here are a few examples are some things that it can't handle that I want it to 
from above if I add another "IN*somenumber" at the end of the format it doesn't parse it

```
names   dates times summary stuffs      infostuffs  stats   names   dates   IN88888888 IN88888888
```

in the above example all it would return is "88888888," completely missing the second one

Other item I would want it to parse is

```
IN88888888 
IN88888888 
IN88888888 
IN88888888 
IN88888888 
IN88888888
```

when it finishes the output is

```
88888888,
IN88888888 
IN88888888 
IN88888888 
IN88888888 
IN88888888
```

Any help or suggestions would be great I have been trying to search on w3schools for like just a generic search function with wild cards but have not came up with any 
here is what I think would be ideal

```
do util end of string(Posted textarea)
   $output = search("IN" . any8numbers);
   echo $output .  ",";
```

Edit1: Based on suggestion here are some things I have done
I tried using a strrpos() as its case insensative but not sure its exactly what I need as it only finds the first or last occurrence (based on what version you use)
I have also tried to use more explode into array and that gets complicated quickly. I believe it is making the problem worse with that as it makes it harder to change in the future if I want to change contents because each explode is relying on the above ones to parse correctly. If it doesn't then it all gets messed up.

I ususally debug this code with basic echos as company laptop will only allow notepad ++ and the PHP server gives no logs and I have no access to it besides storing and running pages

Maybe I should take the text area explode it into an array of individual strings then test if each item in the arry starts with 'IN' then strip it.

Other suggestions?

Comment: Please considering sharing with us what you have tried so far to accomplish you desired results. Clearly you have an idea of how to code - show what you have attempted and we can help from there.

Comment: Alright, I wouldn't say I'm fantastic, this took me quite a while to produce and it was really based on trial and error on saving it then retrying it. its been a few years since I have coded PHP 
I have tried to use the function below but I don't think it is entirely suited for purpose as based on the W3 page it only finds the first or last occurrence and I couldn't use wildcards.

`strrpos() `


 I can't really tell you the exact code I used in previous attempts as I continually overwrite it
I have also tried doing more exploded arrays but it doesn't do anything

Comment: That looks like a job for regular expressions and `preg_match_all`. Stripping numbers from string is a fairly simple task with regex.

Comment: didn't even know regex could even be used in PHP. Then I can probably implement that quite easily as my company and I use regex every day. Will look into this

Comment: is there any function that will take the text area and put it into a giant array? I use 'explode' currently but my main problem is it doesn't catch the carriage return as I set the delimiter to a space then I have to re iterate through it to catch the carriage return